# Validate text in maskedTextBox

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have three strings like this (entered into three masked text boxes):

```
string string1="£1,252,52";
string string2="£1,   .52";
string string3="£2, 52.52;
```

The second and third string are invalid.  How can I identify string2 as being invalid.  I have to say:

If there is a blank space after a number then the string is invalid i.e.

```
if (blank space after number)
return true;
else
return false;
```

I have done this in SQL before using the LIKE statement.  However, I cannot figure out how to do it in C#.

Comment: Is this a valid string "£ 1,252.52"? What about " £1,252.52" or "£1,252.52 "?

Comment: Stuart, the input mask is: £999,999.00.  How can I validate that?

Comment: Can you simply then just check for the presence of any white space ? string.Contains.

Comment: Have a look at [these functions](http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/csharp-articles/csharp-string-function/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular expression to validate your input. like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textbox1 =  new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox(); 
            textbox1.Text = "£1,252,52";
            string pattern = @"^\£?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{0,3}(.\d{0,3})?|\d{1,3}(.\d{2})?)$";
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textbox1.Text, pattern))
            {
                //if string matched
            }
            else
            {
                //if not matched
            }
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this find when there are no columns e.g. .50 for 50p?

Comment: I have changed the pattern to include 50p also. you can try this pattern here:   http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Can you summarise what this does please? Thanks again.

Comment: it matches your currency format with the pattern what I have provided in the above code. for £.50 you have to specify £0.50. if string matched then if block will execute otherwise else block

Comment: thanks.  0.5 seems to succeed i.e. without the 0 on the end.

Comment: kindly mark this as answer if it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143160/discussion-between-mohd-ismail-siddiqui-and-w0051977).

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your text like this:

```
string string1 = "£1,252.52";

var pattern = @"^\£\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.)(\d+)";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);

return regex.IsMatch(string1)
```

The regex `^\£\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.)(\d+)` validates numbers in occordance with your template of £999,999.00. It makes sure the input starts with a £, contains commas after every 3 characters and has a decimal space.

Test: [Regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%C2%A3%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%28%2C%5Cd%7B3%7D%29*%28%5C.%29%28%5Cd%2B%29&i=%C2%A31%2C252.52%0D%0A%C2%A39%2C999.00%0D%0A%C2%A3999%2C999.00%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Negative%20Test%20cases%20%28Don%27t%20work%20due%20to%20misplacement%20of%20commas%20or%20decimals%0D%0A%C2%A31%2C%20%20%20.52%0D%0A%C2%A32%2C%2052.52%0D%0A%C2%A39999%2C99.00%0D%0A%C2%A39999999.00%0D%0A%C2%A39999999)

Comment: Thanks.  Will this find when there are no columns e.g. .50 for 50p?

Comment: @w0051977 yes it works for £0.50 as well. Try it out in [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%c2%a3%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%28%2c%5cd%7b3%7d%29*%28%5c.%29%28%5cd%2b%29&i=%c2%a31%2c252.52%0d%0a%c2%a39%2c999.00%0d%0a%c2%a3999%2c999.00%0d%0a%c2%a30.50%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2f+Negative+Test+cases+%28Don%27t+work+due+to+misplacement+of+commas+or+decimals%0d%0a%c2%a31%2c+++.52%0d%0a%c2%a32%2c+52.52%0d%0a%c2%a39999%2c99.00%0d%0a%c2%a39999999.00%0d%0a%c2%a39999999).